# Auto fill macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to create a loop that fills in columns with the following data:
Column A should populate with a number from 1 to 10000,
Column B should populate with a today's date and increment with the number,
Column C should populate with number of a day of the week so repeating from 1 to 7 every week,
Column D should populate with a day of the week from Monday to Sunday (text).

I think this could be achieved with a For ...Next loop. More complicated would be with the dates...
Could you please give me a hint how to go about this? 
THank you

Comment: If you are going to loop, use a memory array and assign the whole array at once.  Do not loop ranges.  It will be slow.

Comment: Why use VBA for that? Fill column A with Excel Autofill, Col B gets a formula `=Today() + A1 -1`; Col C `=WeekDay(B1)` and Col D `=B2`; format it with `DDDD` so that only the day is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub mm()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim weekDayNames As Variant
    With Range("A1:A10000")
        .Formula = "=ROW()"
        .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Today()+RC1-1"
        .Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(RC2,1)"
        With .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        weekDayNames = Application.Transpose(.Offset(, 2).Value)
        For i = 1 To UBound(weekDayNames)
            weekDayNames(i) = WeekdayName(weekDayNames(i), False, vbSunday)
        Next
        .Offset(, 3).Value = Application.Transpose(weekDayNames)
    End With
End Sub
```